# Convert List of Set<String> to Set<String> using JAVA 8 Streams

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream, flatmap

Is there any possibility to convert a List of Set to Set using java 8 streams.
Here my List :

```
// Get Header Columns to display in EXCEL FILE

    List<Set<String>> keysQuery = listExtractQglobal.parallelStream()
                    .map(m -> m.keySet()).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the type of `listExtractQglobal` variable?

Comment: List of Map : List<Map<String, Object>>

Answer (score 2):

Just use a flatMap

```
Set<String> a = keysQuery.stream().flatMap(s -> s.stream()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

As the comment indicated you can also replace the lambda function with lambda reference

```
 Set<String> a = keysQuery.stream().flatMap(Set::stream).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: Or using a method reference: `.flatMap(Set::stream)`.

Comment: @JavaProgramer please accept the answer if the problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is how you create your list:

```java
List<Set<String>> keysQuery = listExtractQglobal.parallelStream()
                    .map(m -> m.keySet()).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

you can actually avoid unnecessary collecting to a list and collect to a set instead:

```java
Set<String> keysQuery = listExtractQglobal.parallelStream()
                                          .map(Map::keySet)
                                          .distinct()
                                          .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                                          .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

---

Btw, I'm not sure why do you need the `distinct` here. Are you looking for distinct sets or distinct keys among all key sets? In latter case you could simply omit the `distinct()`, since the resulting `Set` contains distinct values by definition:

```java
Set<String> keysQuery = listExtractQglobal.parallelStream()
                                          .map(Map::keySet)
                                          .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                                          .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `Stream#mapMulti` from [java-16](/questions/tagged/java-16) instead of `Stream#flatMap` as it has an overhead of possibly creating empty or very small streams

```java
Set<String> keysQuery = listExtractQglobal.parallelStream()
                                          .map(Map::keySet)
                                          .mapMulti((Set<String> set, Consumer<String> consumer) -> {
                                              set.forEach(consumer::accept);
                                          })
                                          .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```